# How does this version of a React change handler work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently creating a component in React. Normally, my change handlers look like this:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
}
```

However, I've recently [seen example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/wjok0?module=/example.js&file=/example.js) that has a change handler that looks like this:

```
handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })
```

It works in the example, and in some code I've implemented- but in other places I've tried it, it doesn't work. What exactly is going on here? Is this some kind of advanced destructuring?

Comment: It looks like they are using semantic-ui-react for their form library. semantic UI passes in the event as the first parameter, and then an object with the name and value as the second parameter to your handler function. This would be specific to semantic-ui-react and not react itself.

Comment: You can take a look at their website https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input and click on the toggle switch near the top under the "Input" heading. The toggle switch will make it so you can see all the props for the Input, which includes the onChange, and shows what it passes in to the onChange function.